# logic based on prompt input giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript

Hello I am new to JavaScript and I can't figure out my problem.
When I enter my code like this it works, if the `birth year + age === 2016` or if it's not `=== 2016` it logs both statements correctly

```
var newAge = function (yearsAlive) {  
  yearsAlive = this.yearBorn + this.age ; 
if (yearsAlive === 2016)  {
    document.write("That Sounds about right to me ! ");
  } else {
    document.write("Your age cant be right , please try again");
  } 
} ; 
var me = {
  name: "Markese" , 
yearBorn: 1991, 
  age: 25,
  years: newAge
} ; 
me.years()
```

But when I try to enter my code, like this, with user input using prompt it doesn't work. I keep getting the `else` log: `Your age cant be right, please try again` even if it is `=== 2016`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var userName = prompt("Whats your name?") ; 
var userBorn = prompt ("Hey " + userName + " What year where you born?") ; 
var userAge = prompt ("hmm so if you were born " + userBorn + " that would make 
you how old today?") ; 
var newAge = function (yearsAlive) {
  yearsAlive = this.yearBorn + this.age ; 
  if (yearsAlive === 2016)  {
    document.write("That Sounds about right to me ! ");
  } else {
    document.write("Your age cant be right , please try again");
  } 
} ; 
var me = {
  name: userName , 
  yearBorn: userBorn, 
  age: userAge,
  years: newAge
} ; 
me.years() ;
```

Comment: Wont the `yearsAlive` variable get a different value, depending on whether it's before or after the person's birthday? (It will) Imagine I'm 10 months old so I say last year was my birth year. I then say 0 because I'm not 1 yet and voila! 2015+0  !=  2016

Comment: Thats 100% correct , I had to switch it over using the Date () function so it can be accurate  . glad you caught that sorry so late! been busy .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your `prompt` function looks like, but I'll assume it's returning a string that the user types in.  In your working code, `me.yearBorn` and `me.age` both contain numeric values.  But in your non-working code, you're assigning a string to those.  So when you later add the two strings together, it's not doing an arithmetic add operation.  It's concatenating the two strings.  So the result will never equal 2016.  You need to convert the strings into numbers using `parseInt()`.  Try this...

```
var me = {
    name: userName , 
    yearBorn: parseInt(userBorn), 
    age: parseInt(userAge),
    years: newAge
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that prompt is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: @moreON - yes, quite possible.  That's returning a `string`.

Comment: Thanks dude that solved my problem , man I love this site already ! ! !

Answer (score 0):

`===` operator means something else. Please refer to this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

What you can try is changing `===` to `==` in your If clause.

Comment: It's actually a good practice to always use strict comparison operators. And please, don't link to w3schools -- they have lots of obsolete information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I came up with. Instead of using an external function you can just hard code the function into the years variable. This of course has it's drawbacks, so I also included a version that uses an external function.

**EDIT: yearsAlive >= 2016, replaced with yearsAlive <= 2016**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

  function init() {
    //simply change this part to reflect your needs.
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    answer.innerHTML = me.years();
  };

  var me = {
    name: "Markese",
    yearBorn: 1991,
    age: 25,
    years: function(){
      yearsAlive = this.yearBorn + this.age;
      if (yearsAlive <= 2016) {
        return yearsAlive;
      } else {
        return 'Your age cant be right , please try again';
      }
    }
  };
```

OR

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

  function init() {
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');

    //pass in the person object to a function
    answer.innerHTML = newAge(me);
  };

  function newAge(person){
    //extract the properties of that object
    yearsAlive = person.yearBorn + person.age;

    //return the proper result (or document.write())
    if (yearsAlive <= 2016) {
      return yearsAlive;
    } else {
      return 'Your age cant be right , please try again';
    }
  }

  var me = {
    name: "Markese",
    yearBorn: 1991,
    age: 25
  };
```

You may want to consider using an actual date object to extract the current year and then use that in place of 2016. That way your code won't break in 2017.

Comment: Thanks a alot , you really helped me look at my code from a different perspective , I think ill go with your way  . really appreciate it !

Comment: Glad to help! This was a fun problem to work on. If you don't mind, can you mark my answer as accepted? Thanks. :)